# activeX control crash on alt+tab

Tags: delphi, mfc, activex

I've implemented an Delphi acitveX control. Everything runs fine on html. After that, I embed that activeX in an MFC application. It's good, except that when I test it, if I alt+tab to another windows(Chrome, for example...) and alt+tab back to my application, it just crashed.
I know that this is a non-clear question, but I have no clues. Any clues to solve this situation? What may go wrong or what events I should take a look at? 
Thanks.
Edit 1:
This is what I got when I use spy++ on it.

```
<04518> 00100B7C S WM_ACTIVATE fActive:WA_INACTIVE fMinimized:False hwndPrevious:(null)
<04519> 00100B7C S WM_ACTIVATETOPLEVEL fActive:False dwThreadID:0025F40C
<04520> 00100B7C R WM_ACTIVATETOPLEVEL
```

Edit 2:
This is what I got from call stack when I break all at the time it hangs

```
mfc100d.dll!CThreadSlotData::GetThreadValue(int nSlot)  Line 248    C++
    mfc100d.dll!CThreadLocalObject::GetData(CNoTrackObject * (void)* pfnCreateObject)  Line 420 + 0x11 bytes    C++
    mfc100d.dll!CThreadLocal<AFX_MODULE_THREAD_STATE>::GetData()  Line 179 + 0xd bytes  C++
    mfc100d.dll!AfxGetModuleThreadState()  Line 477 + 0x11 bytes    C++
    mfc100d.dll!afxMapHWND(int bCreate)  Line 289 + 0x5 bytes   C++
    mfc100d.dll!CWnd::FromHandlePermanent(HWND__ * hWnd)  Line 324 + 0x7 bytes  C++
    mfc100d.dll!AfxWndProc(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam)  Line 405 + 0x9 bytes    C++
    mfc100d.dll!AfxWndProcBase(HWND__ * hWnd, unsigned int nMsg, unsigned int wParam, long lParam)  Line 420 + 0x15 bytes   C++
```

Edit 3:
I'm using Visual studio 2010, the call stack tell that application hangs in this function, line 2, from afxtls.cpp. Please anyone shed some lights on how to solve this.

```
inline void* CThreadSlotData::GetThreadValue(int nSlot)
{
    EnterCriticalSection(&m_sect);
    ASSERT(nSlot != 0 && nSlot < m_nMax);
    ASSERT(m_pSlotData != NULL);
    ASSERT(m_pSlotData[nSlot].dwFlags & SLOT_USED);
    ASSERT(m_tlsIndex != (DWORD)-1);
    if( nSlot <= 0 || nSlot >= m_nMax ) // check for retail builds.
    {
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_sect);
        return NULL;
    }

    CThreadData* pData = (CThreadData*)TlsGetValue(m_tlsIndex);
```

Comment: Use a debugger. You didn't even tell us what the error is. What chance have we got?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't even know where to toggle the breakpoint.  I feel it hopeless too.

Comment: Use the debugger. Configure it to break on an exception. Learn to ibclude error details in your question. Edit this question to supply missing details.

Comment: I did it, but it didn't break anywhere. I config debug to stop with any execption, handled or not-handled.

Comment: Keep trying. Hard to know what to suggest if you refuse to tell us what the error is. "It just crashed" is no use to us.

Comment: Yes, I will try. I don't refuse to tell the error. I just can't find out. I've just added some more info I got from call stack.

Comment: Of course you can find out. When you say "it crashed" that's not good enough. Describe exactly what happens.

Comment: It also sounds as though you are using the wrong debugger. If the code fails in the activex control, you need to use the delphi debugger.

Comment: It looks like you've got a deadlock on that critical section. The debugger ought to be able to identify which thread owns the critical section.

Comment: Thanks David. I don't really figure out why, but this project is just the sample project. After 4 times recreate it, the problems just gone. I've no idea why, may be a charming-time.